# The tag "clean" on stack overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

On Stack Overflow there is a tag called [clean](/questions/tagged/clean), which currently has 110 questions. Those 110 questions seem to be about very different things. After a quick skim through the following topics are currently covered by that tag:

- The "clean" make target and the related "clean" action in some IDEs
- The `git clean` command of `git`
- Making your code clean up temporary files and resources after they're no longer needed
- The concept of "clean code"
- The Clean programming language

Clearly all of those topics should not be covered by the same tag (and some of them probably don't need their own tag at all).

Usually I'd say the tag should be about the programming language and everything else should go elsewhere. However of the 110 questions in [clean](/questions/tagged/clean) only 3 are about the programming language ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126210/the-clean-programming-language-in-the-real-world), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643199/how-to-list-the-files-of-a-directory-in-clean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267760/how-can-a-time-function-exist-in-functional-programming)), so I'm not sure whether that's really enough to warrant it occupying the whole tag.

So let's discuss this: Which of the topics currently covered by [clean](/questions/tagged/clean) deserves its own tag and what should the name of each tag be? Does a programming language that only has three questions deserve its own tag? Should that tag be [clean](/questions/tagged/clean) or maybe something like [clean-language](/questions/tagged/clean-language) to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: I think the "clean" tag should be blacklisted, then "clean-language" creeated, there must allraady be a good tag for "clean code", I don't think the others need their own tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Ok, should I go ahead and add a [tag:clean-language] tag to the three questions about the language (one of which is now entirely untagged) as Ian suggested?

Comment: I don't know if it even matters; if there have been three questions about something in the THREE YEARS of Stack Overflow, does this justify a whole tag? I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe not, but which tag should we give the untagged question if there's no clean tag? Obviously it needs to be tagged as something. Also in one of the questions I gave an answer that specifically talked about Clean because the question was tagged with Clean (though it was not mentioned in the body of the question). Without the tag it just seems random, that I'd be talking about such an obscure language like clean for a whole paragraph.

Comment: meh, IMHO I'd delete that question, it's very 'general reference' obvious

Comment: "General reference" implies that the answer can be found in the documentation, which does not seem to be the case here (mostly because the Clean documentation seems to be quite lackluster). I had to read the source to find the name of the function the OP needed. So it's not as trivial a question as it seems on first sight and not just a duplication of information that could have been easily found elsewhere.

Comment: ok, fine, tag it as you see fit